# getting error Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the same error as mentioned in the below link
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-139

I am using Spring 3.2.4 and even i tried with 4.0.2 but i dont know which version of spring jpa i need to use to resolve the problem as mentioned in the link.I am using servicemix and i have added my service log for your information please help me

Here is my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/bean
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">                                                  
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.organisation.test.persistence">
</jpa:repositories>      
</beans>
```

SERVICE LOG

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins$Plugin.resolve(NamespacePlugins.java:82)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins.doResolve(NamespacePlugins.java:168)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins.resolve(NamespacePlugins.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.TrackingUtil$OsgiServiceHandler.invoke(TrackingUtil.java:123)[111:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.resolve(Unknown Source)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.DelegatedNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DelegatedNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:56)[111:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1433)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)[81:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 more
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you expect from a single exception and no context information that people can guess at what you're doing and offer advice?

Comment: sryy Billy Frost this is the first time i am posting here. I have added my file please look into it and also i have added a jira link the same exception i am getting. I am using spring 3.2.4 and I am using servicemix and i am not able to find which version of spring-jpa i need use.

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-commons-core depends on spring-context, refer this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core/1.4.1.RELEASE)

So, you need to use the version of spring that is shipped with the ServiceMix version you are using.
Hope that helps.